# Azure Durable Function HttpStart failure: Webhooks are not configured

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-durable-functions

I have deployed Azure Durable Http Triggered Function app in Azure Kubernetes Service. I used Visual Studio Code to create the function app. I have followed instructions from this this [article](https://dev.to/anirudhgarg_99/scale-up-and-down-a-http-triggered-function-app-in-kubernetes-using-keda-4m42) and [Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda#deploying-a-function-app-to-kubernetes).

```
Function runtime: 3.0.2630
Python version: 3.7.7
azure-functions: 1.3.1
azure-functions-durable: 1.0.0b9
```

Here is my HttStart `function.json` file looks like,

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "orchestrationClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

This application works perfectly in my local environment. After deploying to AKS cluster, when I call URL, it throws the following expection

```
fail: Function.HelloWorldHttpStart[3]
      Executed 'Functions.HelloWorldHttpStart' (Failed, Id=e7dd35a1-2001-4f11-396f-d251cbd87a0d, Duration=82ms)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.HelloWorldHttpStart
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Webhooks are not configured
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.HttpApiHandler.ThrowIfWebhooksNotConfigured() in d:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\HttpApiHandler.cs:line 737
```

Is there any configuration I missed out? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` environment variable with `<ip-address>:<port>` as the value, where `<ip-address>:<port>` refers to the address that can be used to reach your function app from outside.

This error happens when you use an API that depends on this environment variable. When running using the local core tools, this value is set to `localhost:7071` automatically. When running in the Azure Functions hosted service, this environment variable is also pre-configured to be the DNS name of the function app (e.g. `myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net`. For other environments, like AKS, you'll need to add this environment variable explicitly and set it to the correct value for your deployment.

Comment: This works for me (Sort of) but I am not authorised to make the request (401) how do get permission to do this in Kubernetes ?

Comment: You need to configure and use a system key to authenticate your request. A similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420817/how-to-retrieve-function-keys-when-azure-function-is-deployed-in-kubernetes (but sadly has no answer). I couldn't find any official docs that describe this, but this PR shows how you can register keys here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/4462. For Durable Functions, I suspect you need to create a secret named `host.systemkey.durabletask_extension` and use that value to authenticate your requests.